# How to instantiate an instance of a class that uses redux Connect

Tags: react-native, redux

I have an API class that has various methods that communicate to a backend like "login, register, createPost" etc. I am connecting this class to a reducer. The reducer contains the [state](http://prntscr.com/hbwpyv) of the user info, which I want to be accessible in my Api class:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

@connect(state => ({
    api: state.api,
}) )
export default class Api extends Component {

    export const login = async({args}) => {

    const url = this.props.api.url.concat('/login/');
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFTOKEN': this.props.api.token
            }
        };
    try {
        const data = await axios.post(url, {"username": args.username, "password": args.password}, config);
        this.props.api.key = data.data.token;
        this.props.api.user = data.data.user;
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
        }
    }
};

    async createPost(args (content of the post)) {
        try {
            const url = this.props.api.url.concat('/post/PostList');
            const Response = await axios.post(url, {...args}, !**this.props.api.key**! );
            return Response;
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

In the first method, I set the imported state.key and state.user (connected via redux) information, and I want to access that in the second method (this.props.api.key I surrounded by stars). I am trying to do it this way because I have a multitude of actions on different screens, and users have to pass their authentication information to the api method they're calling on top of whatever they're trying to do in order to be able to execute whatever respective action. I figure that it's easier to pass the user info in my Api class instead of importing the Api state into every different file I call the actions in.

The issue I'm running into is I can't instantiate a new object of api like

```
const api = new Api();
```

Because it gives me an error "cannot read property store of undefined," so I can't call the actions api.login(withArgs) in respective files, and if I make the methods static they won't have access to this.props.whatever

How do I instantiate a class that's connected to the global state of redux, or how can I access the info in that global state outside of my reducer file?

Answer (score 0):

Since Api extends React.Component, why are you trying to instantiate the class yourself vs. letting React render it for you?

```
ReactDOM.render(<Api store={store} />)
```

or if you are not using JSX

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Api, { store })
```